# Angular <a> tag stop working when form is used

Tags: angular

Basically i have made header and am calling that header in every page. but when i use form in body the  tag in header stops working (not clickable).
**Here is my header code:**

```
iv class="main-panel">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
        <div class="container-fluid">                
                <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"><a routerLink="/abc"><p style="float:left;">Date</p></a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"><a routerLink="/dummy"><p style="float:left;">Sometext</p></a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"><a routerLink="/logout"><p style="float:left;">Log out</p></a></div>             
             </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Now i call it using `<app-header></app-header>` in every page. But when i use form in that body the header links stop working.
**Here is a picture before i use form** 
 [image] 
**Here is a picture after i use form** [image]

Comment: Check the browser console for any errors.

Comment: And don't put app-header in every page. Put it once and only once, in your root component.

Comment: Thank you both for your ideas. I checked the console and found the problem which i was missing i think i have resolved it for now, but i will put this through testing first. AND AGAIN THANK YOU

Comment: i can;t put app-header in every page as there is also login screen, which dont need that header

Comment: Then check if the URL is the URL of the login page, or use two different parent routes. Putting this component in the template of each component is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your header component in the (root) appComponent.html to render in all pages,  then make a separate formComponet.

Comment: not the answer i was looking for. problem was that i was using ngmodel in ngform and not using name attribute with it which caused problem

Comment: and the reason this idea is not feasible for me is because i have login screen, which doesn't require that header so putting header in root will cause problem

Comment: Login wasn't mentioned, but anyway showing the form would of been a good idea?